# Design an algorithm with less time complexity to solve this problem

Tags: python, list, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

### [Click to show my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urruy.png)

This what I came up with, but I still want a more efficient one. I used python language, but i know java too. What matters is the efficient algorithm.
The question based on gathering the indices. I mean in list 1, the first number is 15 (which is at index 0).. the mission is to find the same number in the second list, but printing its index. So, list1 number 15 is at list2 at index 2. and so on..
If you do not know python or java, it does not matter, I just want to know the efficient algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: make a map from L2, iterate over L1 and check in map

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should paste the code directly within the question as opposed to linking to an external site. As for a hint, you should consider either using an auxiliary data structure or sorting, both of which are more efficient than your current brute-force approach.

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not** a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the elements are unique in both lists and the length is same then you can use:

```
list1 = [15, 12, 13, 19, 14] 
list2 = [19, 13, 15, 12, 14]

for index,i in enumerate(list1):
    print(f'A[{index}] with B[{list2.index(i)}]')
```

Output:

```
A[0] with B[2]
A[1] with B[3]
A[2] with B[1]
A[3] with B[0]
A[4] with B[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done nice work but if you just want to know the specified position of values in both lists, you can just use sort() method to match both positions and know the value at each index.
Code here..

```
list1 = [63,3,82,45,1]
list2 = [3,82,63,1,45]
list1.sort()
list2.sort()
for I in range(len(list1)):
    print('Position at index',I,'in both the lists is',list1[I])
```